# how do i use angular js routes for node js application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm having a issue with routing with angular js when i'm using node js.

Controller PATH

***public_html/dev/inquiry/js/controllers/poolController.js***

```
app.controller('poolController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    "use strict";    
                $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/pool'
            }).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.pools = data;            
            }); 
}]);
```

server.js PATH

***public_html/dev/inquiry/server.js***

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var obj = ['id':5];

    app.get('/api/pool', function(req, res) {
            res.json(obj);
    });

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

**And I'm running server js by consoling this**

```
node /home/abcdef/public_html/dev/inquiry/server.js
```

So far i got a empty response. what i missed here ?

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: no errors. i think i can't understand this routing

Comment: Be sure to check both server console and browser console

Comment: Yes check both console

Comment: do i want to so something else when using ssl ?

Comment: var obj = ['id':5]; what object did you try to create here? Why not using {} instead of []?

Comment: If my previous comment\answer didnt work, try using error method and not only success, this way you will receive an error on your controller if thats the case.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a typo in your server js file, obj is not a json object and thats why the response is empty.

When you define a JS object which contains a property (id in your case) you should use curly brackets:

```
var obj = {'id':5};
```

see [Javascript object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

Answer (score 0):

obj is not in json format.

try,

```
obj={'id':5}
```

Comment: Thats what I wrote 45 mins ago and got -1 for it :\ Instead duplicating my answer you can just support my answer.